# Get previous record in SQL Server based on file date

Tags: sql-server

I have a records of file run in an ETL. The problem statement is the get only the status of pervious file based on the date for the current file.

| TransactionID | FileName | Status | FileDate | TransactionDate | SrcFile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CallData_20200731 | 5 | 2020-07-31 | 2021-04-12 21:11:42.967 | CallData |
| 2 | CallData_20200831 | 5 | 2020-08-31 | 2021-04-12 21:12:37.387 | CallData |
| 3 | CallData_20200930 | 6 | 2020-09-30 | 2021-04-12 21:12:51.437 | CallData |
| 4 | CallData_20201031 | 6 | 2020-10-31 | 2021-04-12 21:13:52.487 | CallData |
| 5 | CallData_20201130 | 6 | 2020-11-30 | 2021-04-12 21:15:06.213 | CallData |
| 6 | CallData_20201231 | 6 | 2020-12-31 | 2021-04-12 21:16:16.870 | CallData |

If I input 'CallData_20200930' then I should get the record for TransactionID 2 only, i.e. the pervious date. The date is also not continuous, so I could subtract 1 day from the current file date. I tried using `LAG()` but it was of not help.

Currently I am able to slice and get the date and filename separated. I am not sure if its the efficient way or there is a better way all together. and current I am getting all the previous record too.

```
declare @filename nvarchar(20),
@srcfile nvarchar(20),
@filedate date

set @filename  = 'CallData_20200930';
set @srcfile = LEFT(@filename,CHARINDEX('_',@filename)-1) 
set @filedate = SUBSTRING(@filename,CHARINDEX('_',@filename)+1,8)

;with cte as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by FileDate) as RN from tblFileStatusLog where SrcFile = @srcfile )
select * from cte where FileDate<@filedate ;
```

Below is the schema and data to help anyone out

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog](
    [TransactionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FileDate] [date] NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SrcFile] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransactionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ([TransactionID], [FileName], [Status], [FileDate], [TransactionDate], [SrcFile]) VALUES (1, N'CallData_20200731', 5, CAST(N'2020-07-31' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-04-12T21:11:42.967' AS DateTime), N'CallData')
INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ([TransactionID], [FileName], [Status], [FileDate], [TransactionDate], [SrcFile]) VALUES (2, N'CallData_20200831', 5, CAST(N'2020-08-31' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-04-12T21:12:37.387' AS DateTime), N'CallData')
INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ([TransactionID], [FileName], [Status], [FileDate], [TransactionDate], [SrcFile]) VALUES (3, N'CallData_20200930', 6, CAST(N'2020-09-30' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-04-12T21:12:51.437' AS DateTime), N'CallData')
INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ([TransactionID], [FileName], [Status], [FileDate], [TransactionDate], [SrcFile]) VALUES (4, N'CallData_20201031', 6, CAST(N'2020-10-31' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-04-12T21:13:52.487' AS DateTime), N'CallData')
INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ([TransactionID], [FileName], [Status], [FileDate], [TransactionDate], [SrcFile]) VALUES (5, N'CallData_20201130', 6, CAST(N'2020-11-30' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-04-12T21:15:06.213' AS DateTime), N'CallData')
INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ([TransactionID], [FileName], [Status], [FileDate], [TransactionDate], [SrcFile]) VALUES (6, N'CallData_20201231', 6, CAST(N'2020-12-31' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-04-12T21:16:16.870' AS DateTime), N'CallData')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] OFF
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblFileStatusLog] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [TransactionDate]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with using `LAG()`.  I think the problem is that you need to `PARTITION` by the `SrcFile` if you're separating things out by the file and date.  Then you can leave your `WHERE` conditions out of the window function and add it to your final query in the `CTE`.

```
declare @filename nvarchar(20),
@srcfile nvarchar(20),
@filedate date

set @filename  = 'CallData_20200930';
set @srcfile = LEFT(@filename,CHARINDEX('_',@filename)-1) 
set @filedate = SUBSTRING(@filename,CHARINDEX('_',@filename)+1,8)

;with cte as
(select *,LAG(TransactionID) over(PARTITION BY SrcFile order by FileDate) as RN from tblFileStatusLog)
select * from cte 
where FileDate = @filedate 
and SrcFile = @srcfile ;
```

Comment: this is still returning two rows

Comment: I edited the query.  There was a less than instead of an equals in the final query.  Try it now.

Comment: tried it. Its returning the same row for which the filename was provided

Comment: Yes, but look at the `RN` column in the return.  That's the previous `TransactionID` you're looking for, right?  Once you have that, you can always join it back to the original table to get all of the details of the previous record if you need it.

Comment: Got it. I have now just joined the cte with the original table on basis on rn and transaction id and it did the job. Thanks a lot @WAMLeslie